# Losing drivers from try version to installation

Tags: drivers, live-usb, 17.04, touchscreen

I got a touchscreen laptop (asus ux501) with 4k screen.

On Ubuntu live version, when I do a `xinput --list`

I got this in the list:

```
USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller
```

And my touchscreen is working, but after I installed Ubuntu, on my real installation, I just lose it...

And the touchscreen is not working anymore.

I tried sudo `modprobe hid_multitouch` and `sudo modprobe hid_generic` but it's not working at all.

Edit: `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57f6 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

EDIT: problem solved !

I just installed the package xserver-xorg-input-libinput (apt told me it was already installed, and ask me to do an autoremove) I did it and I got my touchscreen back !

Comment: Can you add the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: @ByteCommander I have no difference between the live version and the installation, I edited the first post

Comment: What about the output of `sudo lshw`? Can you find the device in there?

Comment: @ByteCommander not on the installation. Must I try the liveversion ?

Comment: I am not sure, if there is a difference in the outputs, that would be interesting. Maybe you should save both outputs to a file so that you can compare them line by line if anything is different. Unfortunately I don't have any devices with touch screens, so I don't really know how exactly they should show up.

Comment: @ByteCommander Touchpad has nothing to do with `lsusb`

Comment: As I understood, Did already solved your issue? Why don't you edit your question, take apart the solution and post as answer? It's very important.  There are many people searching for touchscreen solutions here at AskUbuntu. Edit your title, too. It's not talking about Touchscreen issue. Doing so, you will earn points.

Comment: @Redbob I already edited my question....

Comment: But you must put the solution below, at Answers section, not mixed with the question. Change the title of the question, because "Losing drivers.. installation" is  vague, doesn't brings any info related to touchscreen

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !

I just had to install the package xserver-xorg-input-libinput. apt told me it was already installed but asked me to launch an autoremove.

I did it, it did some cleaning, some reconfigure. And I got my touchscreen back.